# How many 20-digit numbers can be formed from {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} such that no 2 consecutive digit is both odd

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many 20-digit numbers can be formed from {${1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}$} such that no 2 consecutive digit is both odd. (Repetition allowed)

I've noticed that the number of odd digit in the number must be less than 11. But i can't progress more than that.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: Try answering these questions. 1.) How many odd numbers can you have at most? 2.) Assume you have $k$ odd numbers, to how many positions can you distribute them? 3.) How many possible values for odd digits and even digits do you have in this case?

Comment: I've tried the method used in here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425493/how-many-6-digit-numbers-have-distinct-digits-but-no-consecutive-digits-both-odd but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I've also tried @AndreasLenz method. I tried to work with the case where the number of odd digits is 1,2,3... but the number of cases is too much

Comment: The comment of @AndreasLenz may well be a better approach than what I am going to suggest.  I suggest using [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  See also the **first part only** of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268763/number-of-solutions-to-equation-of-varying-size-with-varying-upper-bound-range/4268835?r=SearchResults&s=1|84.5623#4268835) for guidance in setting up an Inclusion-Exclusion framework.  ...see next comment

Comment: I would create variables $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_{19}$, where $A_k$ represents the set of all possible $20$ digit numbers that have two consecutive odd digits, starting in position $k$.  Then, the problem reduces to enumerating $\left|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_{19}\right|.$

Comment: An alternative approach that may or may not be workable, and might be easier is **recursion**.  That is, how many $2$ digit numbers are there such that there is no occurrence of $2$ consecutive odd digits?  Then, how many such $3$ digit numbers are there?  Then, if $f(n)$ is the number of such $n$ digit numbers, what is the relationship between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$.  This approach might allow you to *manually* enumerate $f(2), f(3), \cdots, f(19), f(20)$.  Note that it is not uncommon for a problem such as the one that you posted to yield to either Inclusion-Exclusion or recursion.

Comment: @RAPTOR Counting 2.) is not possible by hand. Are you aware of the method of stars and bars? In particular the case, where the bins are not allowed to be empty is of interest to you (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one_2)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will let you know if i need anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Let $x_n$ be the number of $n$-digit numbers which can be formed from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ such that no two consecutive digits are both odd.

We split $x_n$ into two parts: $a_n$ counts the numbers where the last digit is odd and $b_n$ counts the ones where the last digit is even. Then $x_n=a_n+b_n$.

Moreover we can easily check that $a_1=5$, $b_1=4$, $a_2=4\cdot 5=20$, $b_2=9\cdot4=36$.

Is there any recurrences which involve $a_n$, $b_n$, $a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1}$?
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I still couldn't get your hint.

Comment: Is there any relation between $a_{n+1}$ and $b_n$? Is there any relation between $b_{n+1}$ and $x_n$?

Comment: Is it $a_{n+1}$ = $b_n * a_n$ and $b_{n+1}$ = 4 $x_{n+1}$. So i need to prove them right?

Comment: The first one is wrong, the second one is correct. Yes, you have to prove them.

Comment: Oh so the first one is just $a_{n+1}$ = $4*b_{n+1}$ right?

Comment: Well that makes sense. You are truly a genius

Comment: Are you just guessing? Are you sing the fact that no 2 consecutive digit is both odd?

Comment: Oh I had some mistake *facepalm*. I do remember the fact. The reason why $a_{n+1}$ = $5*b_{n}$ is those $a_{n}$ can't take odd digit as their next

Comment: Now it is correct and you are ready to solve your problem

Comment: Since I've already know how to solve Recurrence Relation so I won't need any more help. Thank you for the hints

Comment: @RAPTOR i think $b_{n+1}=4x_{n+1}$ would have been $b_{n+1}=4x_{n}$

Comment: Bullbasaur is correct. I missed that. The recurrences are: $b_{n+1}=4x_{n}$ and $a_{n+1}=5b_{n}$